# Comparing two TIME variables using java

Tags: java, android, comparison

I want to compare the system time with manually given time,  this program is not satisfying the condition. How can i do this in 24hrs format.

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();  
    String am_pm;  
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);  
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);  
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);  
    if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)  
      am_pm = "AM";  
    else  
      am_pm = "PM";    
    String time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + am_pm ;  
    String time1 =  12 + ":" + 40 + ":" + 00 + " " + "PM";  
    if(time==time1)    
    {     
        display(time);  
    }  
    else   
    {  
        display(time);  
    }
```

I have to do it in android Application. So pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java, you compare strings using string1.equals(string2), not using ==

Answer (score 5):

This gives the hour (0-23):

```
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings and other objects should be compared with .equals() method, not == opertor